# Geometry Nodes: Stylized Hair Lighting Only Works Along the Positive Y-Coordinate

Tags: geometry-nodes, hair, shader-nodes

**The File is provided.** I'm working on stylized hair using **hair curves** and **geometry nodes**.

The stylized hair geometry node setup was created using this video for reference by Dean Zarkov: [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8AWkOqbCNIw)

I wanted to utilize a different shader setup, similar to the Arcane Hair Shader Tutorial from Lightning Boy Studio, as shown in this video here: [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXuReln3XD0)

I was relatively successful in adapting Lightning Boy Studio's Arcane Hair Shader to work with the geometry node stylized hair setup, although there's an issue. **The lighting seems to only work along the Positive Y-Coordinate.**

No matter how it's styled, the side facing the Positive Y-Coordinate will always be lit up correctly and the opposing side will always utilize the **Translucent BSDF** light instead of the normal lighting.

**Here are some examples:**

This first image is the optimal result that I would like the hair to look in all angles unless light is shining through it.

[image: Optimal Result]

This second image shows the problem. The BSDF lighting (the light blue) is being used instead of the normal lighting even though it isn't shining through the hair.

[image]

This third image shows that even using only a single Sun lamp results in the same outcome.

[image]

I'm not sure how to fix this problem, as I'm not knowledgable enough with nodes and how they each function.

**My Assumption:**

According to the explanation on how **Translucent BDSF** nodes work by Lightning Boy Studio: [Link](https://youtu.be/FXuReln3XD0?t=1437), it doesn't receive any light from the front, instead it receives light from the back.

I'm assuming that the **geometry node** doesn't know what is considered the "front" and the "back" of the stylized hair. So even though the hair system seems as though it should have an obvious front and back, since brushing the stylized hair automatically adjusts it to the correct side, the shader doesn't recognize this. I'm presuming I need to somehow create a local axis of the hair and then adjust the shader to follow this, but I'm not sure how.

**Other quirks:**

Also, for some reason my **Specular BDSF** setup isn't behaving as I would expect it to; the light isn't getting reflected in it like a mirror. Instead, it's behaving similar to a Diffuse BSDF, where the light information doesn't move as the camera moves. This isn't a big deal to me, since the result still looks fine, but if anyone knows how to fix this too, that would be nice.

**File:**
[image]